# Investigate for uniform convergence $\sum e^{-n\tan(x)}, 0 < x < \pi/2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

by Weierstrass sequence is not selected, the derivative at 0 is not drawn, I do not know

$\sum e^{-n\tan(x)}, 0 < x < \pi/2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\exp(-n\tan(x))=(\exp(-\tan(x)))^n$, substituting $u=\exp(-\tan(x))$ gives geometric series, which is convergent for $|u|<1$.